# binding to com events

Tags: c#, .net, com

I am writing C# .NET code to consume a COM object.
The COM interface has a method and an event called the same name.

The method is called IncidentCommander and has signature:

```
CommsLibrary.IGuardianComms.IncidentCommander(int, string, sbyte)
```

The event, also called IncidentCommander, has signature:

```
CommsLibrary.IGuardianCommsEvents.IncidentCommander(int, int, string, sbyte, System.DateTime)
```

When I try to bind to the event with:

```
_modasCommsLibrary.CrewUpdate += ModasCommsLibraryOnCrewUpdate;
```

.NET gives the following compilation error:

"Cannot assign to 'IncidentCommander' because it is a 'method group."

I believe that it because I am trying to bind to the method.

Is there any way of forcing .NET to bind to the event rather than the method?
I've tried using reflection to get the events and manually bind it, but this doesn't work either.

The code that I used was:

```
// bind to the incident commander event (because it has the same name as a method...)
var eventInfo = _modasCommsLibrary.GetType().GetEvent("IncidentCommander");
var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("ModasCommsLibraryOnIncidentCommander");
var handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, _modasCommsLibrary, methodInfo);
```

I've also tried casting the COM instance to the event interface, as follows (as Hans suggested):

```
((IGuardianCommsEvents) _modasCommsLibrary).IncidentCommander += ModasCommsLibraryOnIncidentCommander;
```

But I get the same error

"Cannot assign to 'IncidentCommander' because it is a 'method group."

Comment: The snippet makes no sense.  Post your *original* code, the one you are having a problem with.  In general, cast the COM object reference to the specific interface type.  Avoid the autogenerated xxxxClass type name.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I've updated. Also tried your suggestion on casting, but it wasn't successful.